# Search Multiple Tables And Return 1 Combined Column MSQL

Tags: sql

I need to write a query, and I'm not sure where to start... A join won't work since I'm basically querying for everything from both tables (for one column).

I have 2 tables, Each table different fields. But each table has 1 field in common i.e. Domains, I need to pull a list of all domains between both of them and return it in 1 column.

So table 1's domain field, and table 2's domain field showing in 1 column below eachother.
Also removing duplicates where there are. So if there's 2 domains that both are the same, I only need to show 1.

Is something like this possible in a SQL Query?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for `UNION` (or `UNION ALL` if you don't want to remove duplicates)

Comment: @HoneyBadger do you have simple an example where you did something similar maybe?